# Limit probability of a complete bipartite random graph $G(n,n,p)$ is connected

Tags: real-analysis, probability, analysis, graph-theory, random-graphs

I need to calculate the following probability limit for a complete bipartite random graph $G(n,n,p)$ in the Erdos-Renyi model:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{P}[G(n,n,p) \text{ is connected}]
\end{equation}
when $np=\ln n + w(n)$ where $w(n)\rightarrow -\infty$ when $n\rightarrow\infty$.

I know that the expected value of the number of isolated vertices in $G(n,n,p)$ is:
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}X=2n(1-p)^n
\end{equation}

Where X stands for the number of isolated vertices of course.

So the graph $G(n,n,p)$ is connected if it doesn't have any isolated vertices then by Markov inequality:

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(X\ge 1)\le \mathbb{E}X
\end{equation}

and so substituting the value of $p$ i get:

\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{P}[G(n,n,p) \text{ is connected}]&=&\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{P}(X\ge1)\leq\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}X\\
&=&\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}2n\bigg(1-\cfrac{\ln n + w(n)}{n}\bigg)^n
\end{eqnarray}

My questions are 2 actually:

1- Is correct what i did?

2- If the answer for 1 is YES. How can i calculate that limit?

Thanks in advance!

The variance for the number of isolated vertices is 
\begin{equation}
 \mathbb{V}X=4n^2(1-p)^n+2n(n-1)(1-p)^{2n}+n^2(1-p)^{2n-1}
\end{equation}
And by Chebyshev inequality:
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbb{P}(X=0)&\leq&\cfrac{\mathbb{V}X}{(\mathbb{E}X)^2}
&\leq&\cfrac{4n^2(1-p)^n+2n(n-1)(1-p)^{2n}+n^2(1-p)^{2n-1}}{4n^2(1-p)^{2n}}
\end{eqnarray}
And sadly once again i got stuck with the limiting probability any hand on this?

Comment: I don't know the answer for your question, but incidentally, do you have any recommendations for a good reference about Random Graph Theory? This problem looks really interesting!

Comment: Yes, you can start with [Svante Janson, Tomasz Luczak, Andrzej Rucinski] book "Random Graphs", [Bela Bollobás] - Random Graphs or [Alon Spencer] "The probabilistic Method"

Answer (score 2):

You are right that if $X$ is the number of isolated vertices, then $P(X \geq 1) \leq E[X]$, because $X$ is a non-negative integer-valued random variable.

Note that on the event that $\{X \geq 1\}$, the graph is *not* connected. Thus $\{X \geq 1\} \subseteq \{G(n,n,p) \text{ is not connected}\}$, and in fact,
$$
P(X \geq 1) \leq P(G(n,n,p) \text{ is not connected}).
$$

So having an *upper* bound on $P(X \geq 1)$ will not help us here. In fact, 
\begin{align*}
E[X] &= 2n \left( 1 - p_n \right)^n = 2 \exp \left( \ln n +  n \ln \left( 1- p_n \right)\right) \\&= 2 \exp \left( \ln n + n (-p_n + O(p_n^2)) \right) \\ &= 2 \exp \left( -\omega_n + O(\ln^2 n/ n) \right) \to \infty,
\end{align*}
as $n \to \infty$.

Now it is possible to show that $P(X \geq 1) \to 1$ (and hence, $P(G(n,n,p) \text{ is not connected}) \to 1$) without so much more work. If you calculate the second moment of $X$, you can use Chebyshev's Inequality to get this fact.